# Python flask and how to show code in a web page

Tags: python, flask

My web framework is Flask.

I would like to create a section of a page that will show java script and html code fragments.  I dont know the lingo for doing this.  Are there any python flask plugins for this?  ANy other type of js libaries?  Again, I need js and html code snippets.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [Prettify](http://code.google.com/p/google-code-prettify/) - Stackoverflow uses this to format code. It will format code on your page and make it look as it does here on this site.

You just include the JavaScript and CSS on your page.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  href="css/colorschemes/prettify.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/prettify/prettify.js"></script>
```

See the setup instructions [here](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html)

Comment: It worked for JS but on for html this showed a button rather than a code snippent....<pre class="prettyprint">
  <input type="test" />
 </pre>

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at [pygments](http://pygments.org/). It can handle a [large number of formats](http://pygments.org/docs/lexers/).