# How to align the header name in json?

Tags: json, css

The below json aligns the column contents towards left.How to align the header "Name" in left.

Header Json:

```
"columns": [
    {
        "title": "Name",
        "align": "Left",
        "width": "25%"
    },
   {
        "title": "Address",
        "align": "Center",
        "width": "20%"
    }
]}
```

Json data for columns:

```
"studentList": [
  {
    "name": "Paulo",
   "address":"US"
  },
   {
    "name": "Andrew",
   "address":"UK"
  },
],
```

Comment: What are you talking about? Do you need to display the json content in a HTML page?

Comment: I get the json contents in html.I need the header "Name" to be aligned towards left.

Comment: Still unclear what you are trying to do, but you probably could use `<pre>` tag

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSON pretty print with highlighting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17862545/json-pretty-print-with-highlighting)